# Android kotlin - unresolved reference for with(context) inside fragment

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, kotlin

This is the code:

```
val bitmap: Bitmap = Picasso.with(context).load(bild_1_url).get()
```

I get unresolved reference for `with`

How to solve it? What is that anyway? Can't find anything about it anywhere

Thanks in advance

Comment: I guess you need to replace context with `requireActivity()`

Comment: _"Can't find anything about it anywhere"_ https://square.github.io/picasso/2.x/picasso/com/squareup/picasso/Picasso.html#with-android.content.Context-

Comment: requireActivity() don't solve the problem

Comment: So what's the solution michael

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Picasso.get().load("http://i.imgur.com/DvpvklR.png").into(imageView);`

I guess you're missing `.get()`.

**Update**

To get the bitmap, use this `Picasso.get().load("url").get()` or `Picasso.get().load("url").into(target)`.

Comment: This isn't it, I alread use this code to put images from url directly into imageview, but with the code in the question I only try to retrieve the bitmap

Comment: But Picasso.get().load("http://i.imgur.com/DvpvklR.png").get() did the trick so I accept your answer :D You should edit it. I guess the code in my question is outdated and bugged

Comment: @donkinged Hey, I've updated the answer. It's almost same as your old code.